# Change Job - Transfer - Company Change in Job Managed sup. org

Tags: workday-api

An employee is hired future dated in Job managed sup. org., at particular entity say xyz with corresponding org. assignments like cost center, region etc.

Now I want to change organizations of this employee to other entity, to other cost center region within same sup. org.

I am not able to do change job for this employee as it is future dated.

How to overcome this problem?

It is part of core HCM. Need workday solution

Answer (score 0):

a few things you can try:

1. If you have the security for it, you can look at the Worker's History and may be able to correct it from the related actions menu on the Assign Organizations BP.
2. You can try a Change Job or Edit Position transaction effective the same date as the hire date to "overwrite" the organizations during the hire.
3. You can rescind the Hire event and re-enter it with the corrected data.